# onselectionchange Javascript event in webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, dom-events

In my Android app I'm attaching a handler for the Javascript `onselectionchange` like this:

```
$(document).on('selectionchange',function(ev){
    alert('Text has been selected');
});
```

This is supposed to be fired when the user selects something (like text) or the selection changes, however it is fired on tap. Does anyone know the reason of this behavior? (Something like this is working in iOS)

Answer (score 0):

"onselectionchange" event is not a cross-browser feature. 
AFAIK, it's only Trident (iexplore) and **recent versions of webkit** (and hence webview) that support text selection events.

That being said, could it be that the version of webkit present on the iOS you tested is more recent than your Android's version?
Also consider that though they both render with webkit, they use totally different javascript engines, hence potentially different behaviour.